# get specific node in documentNode on C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-crawler, innertext, selectsinglenode

i have an html code in my html page :

```
<span itemprop="title" data-andiallelmwithtext="15" aria-current="page" aria-label="you are on laptop categories">laptops</span>
```

in my crawler , i'm trying to see on what page i'm in it, so i have tried this:

```
var productLocation = dc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@itemprop='title']").InnerText;
```

the problem is that i have more the one Node with itemprop='title'

how to reach the specific node, in order to get

```
productLocation = "you are on laptop categories"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your xpath expression to

```
//span[@itemprop='title'and @aria-label='you are on laptop categories']
```

or

```
//span[@itemprop='title'][@aria-label='you are on laptop categories']
```